# Forwarding IMAP Messages with Perl

Tags: php, perl, imap

I need to handle some mail. I already have a script built that can parse through a mailbox and perform several actions like save attachments, move email to a folders and other administrative tasks. A few of the emails are identified as rogue during this process and need to be forwarded. The messages may or may not have one or more attachments and are dumped into their own folder labeled `fwd`.

I can create and send new email messages but am having trouble finding information on forwarding or replying to existing email. One solution would be to save the parts (body, subject, attachments) to a database and construct a new message with [`MIME::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aLite) but this seems inefficient at best.

I am handling the email with [`Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aIMAP%3a%3aSimple%3a%3aSSL) and [`MIME::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aParser).

Since the email is dumped into a temporary folder for holding I am not totally against using a PHP script to handle the messages, but prefer something in line with my current Perl handler to execute the task.

Looking for some helpful info to help complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into CPAN at `Mail::Box`, a rich (and a bit complex) module handling mail messages, including primitives such as message->copy and message->reply.

For documentation and examples, author's website is at `http://perl.overmeer.net/mailbox/`